# Find a view (button) which a motion event ends on

Tags: java, android, android-menu

**Problem**

I'm looking to create the effect where a initial press of a button sets the visibility of 3 other buttons from gone to visible. After swiping towards and ending on one of the newly visible buttons I want to kick off a different activity.

My problem is that regardless of method I use to get the position of the views (using Rect objects, findNearestTouchable) and the position touch event (using onTouch/Gestures with ACTION_UP) they never seem to match up and i'm never able to return the view I want;

**Desired Functionality**

A motion event which starts from the press of a button and ends on another button, to return the id/view object of the button it ends on.

My main_menu.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="Button"        
        android:tag="1"

        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="36dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="19dp"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button1"
        android:text="Button"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:tag="3" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button3"
        android:text="Button"
        android:visibility="gone" 
        android:tag="2"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:text="Button"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:tag="4" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Current attempt at Activity, which doesn't set  `foundit` (I am very open to completely different implementations)

```
public class Menu extends Activity {
    private GestureDetector gestureDetector;
    View.OnTouchListener gestureListener;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_menu);

        gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new MyGestureDetector());
        gestureListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                View findViewById2 = findViewById(R.id.button2);
                View findViewById3 = findViewById(R.id.button3);
                View findViewById4 = findViewById(R.id.button4);
                findViewById2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                findViewById3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                findViewById4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
            }
        };
        View button = findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnTouchListener(gestureListener);

    }

    class MyGestureDetector extends SimpleOnGestureListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX,
                float velocityY) {

            View foundit = null;
            ViewGroup menu = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.button1).getParent();
            for (int numChildren = menu.getChildCount(); numChildren >= 0; --numChildren) {
                View child = menu.getChildAt(numChildren - 1);
                if (child instanceof Button) {
                    Rect bounds = new Rect();
                    child.getHitRect(bounds);
                    if (bounds.contains((int) e2.getX(), (int) e2.getY())) {
                        foundit = child;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (foundit != null) {
                Log.i("found", "FOUND IT");
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }
    }

}
```

Does anyone have any insight?

**Edit**:

testing the following:

```
    gestureListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            View findViewById2 = findViewById(R.id.button2);
            View findViewById3 = findViewById(R.id.button3);
            View findViewById4 = findViewById(R.id.button4);
            findViewById2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            findViewById3.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            findViewById4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                Log.i("TOUCH X IS", Float.toString(event.getRawX()));
                Log.i("TOUCH Y IS", Float.toString(event.getRawY()));
            }
            for (int numChildren = ((ViewGroup) v.getParent())
                    .getChildCount(); numChildren >= 0; --numChildren) {
                View child = ((ViewGroup) v.getParent())
                        .getChildAt(numChildren - 1);
                if (child instanceof Button) {
                    Rect bounds = new Rect();
                    child.getHitRect(bounds);
                    Log.i(child.getTag().toString() + " CENTER X IS",
                            Float.toString(bounds.exactCenterX()));
                    Log.i(child.getTag().toString() + " CENTER Y IS",
                            Float.toString(bounds.exactCenterY()));
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    };
```

yields the following LogCat output:

`07-06 01:12:58.245: TOUCH X IS(20965): 394.0`

07-06 01:12:58.245: TOUCH Y IS(20965): 297.0

07-06 01:12:58.245: 4 CENTER X IS(20965): 392.0

07-06 01:12:58.245: 4 CENTER Y IS(20965): 219.0

07-06 01:12:58.245: 2 CENTER X IS(20965): 240.0

07-06 01:12:58.250: 2 CENTER Y IS(20965): 219.0

07-06 01:12:58.250: 3 CENTER X IS(20965): 95.0

07-06 01:12:58.250: 3 CENTER Y IS(20965): 219.0

07-06 01:12:58.250: 1 CENTER X IS(20965): 240.0

07-06 01:12:58.250: 1 CENTER Y IS(20965): 345.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting the SubView, If its within Linear Layout or GridLayout is possible by below method.

|*| I have shown u how to get SubView if Views are placed vertically inside LinearLayout.

```
NamVyuVar.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener()
{
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent MsnEvtPsgVar)
    {
        switch (MsnEvtPsgVar.getActionMasked())
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                Log.d("TAG", "onTouch: ACTION_DOWN");
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                LinearLayout NamLloVav = (LinearLayout)view;
                float SubVyuHytVal = NamLloVav.getChildAt(0).getHeight();
                float TchPntYcoVal = MsnEvtPsgVar.getY();
                int NamIdxVal = (int) (TchPntYcoVal / SubVyuHytVal);

                View NamIdxVyuVav = NamLloVav.getChildAt(NamIdxVal)

            // CodTodo With the Indexed View NamIdxVyuVav :

                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                Log.d("TAG", "onTouch: ACTION_UP");
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
});
```

|*| Similarly If u want to get SubView if Views are placed horizontally inside LinearLayout Change below 3 lines.

```
float SubVyuWdtVal = NamLloVav.getChildAt(0).getWidth();
float TchPntXcoVal = MsnEvtPsgVar.getX();
int NamIdxVal = (int) (TchPntXcoVal / SubVyuWdtVal);
```

|*| Same technique can be applied for Grid Layout as well.

Comment: Thank you for an answer to a very old question, it's been a long time since I've done any android development, but this makes me what to see if this works.

Answer (score 0):

In your gesture listener, check for when the MotionEvent is MotionEvent.ACTION_UP and use the coords event.getX() and event.getY(), then determine what view is at those coordinates.

```
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
  if (event == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
    int x = event.getX();
    int y = event.getY();
    //find what view is at x, y
  }
}
```

You would trigger some flag when the first button is pressed (either with onClick or when the motion event is ACTION_DOWN). Then the above would get fired when they lift their finger.

**Edit**: Be sure to use event.getY() and not event.getRawY(). The calculations are different, and the bounds of the button are calculated the same way that getY() is

Comment: I've tried this, unfortunately it has the same problems; the event's x and y don't seem to match the view's co-ords even if the ACTION_UP is fired right on top of them.

Comment: Do you have an example of what values are getting sent for the touch and what the actual bounds of the view is at that time?

Comment: The problem I see is that the GestureDetector isn't attached to anything. You never attach gestureDetector to a view.

Comment: After some testing, it turns out the problem is with the use of event.getRawY(). Try using event.getRawY() and event.getY(). they return different values. event.getY() actually returns the correct value, which is within the bounds of the rectangle.

Comment: I see the difference between getY and getRawY, it seems to me that the former is relative to the start touch and the latter is relative to the whole screen. After testing getY on the ACTION_UP, I still don't get the correct matching of co-ords with either getY or getRawY on the ACTION_DOWN. getY is returning a negative number; while getRawY is returning the same incorrect value as in the original post.

Thanks for the help, Though it's frustrating that I can't figure this out,